# Using tweepy to follow people tweeting a specific hashtag

Tags: python, for-loop, tweepy

This is one of my first python projects and I'm using Tweepy to trying to search for a specific hashtag and follow those people tweeting that hashtag.  I don't understand why this doesn't work and I've tried to append followers to  list but nothing either.  I've read the tweepy docs and this is what I've come up with:

```
import tweepy 
import time

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="#kenbone").items():
    api.create_friendship(screen_name = follower)
    print(follower)
```

Comment: When you state "this doesn't work" you need to be more specific about what's not working. What do you expect to happen, and what actually happens? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

The screen_name is part of the author attribute, this works for me

```
api.create_friendship(screen_name = follower.author.screen_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Want you are getting in your loop, the variable `follower`, is a `user` object with a huge lot of information about the user, and not just a name as you seem to believe. To get the screen name of a `user` object, use `follower.screen_name`:

```
api.create_friendship(screen_name = follower.screen_name)
```